# Texture packer trim sprites with CreateJS

Tags: html, createjs, texturepacker

Does Createjs have any support for trimming sprites with texturepacker ( removing the alpha pixels in the actual sheet) but displaying the sprite with the alpha in game.

If it does not support it does anyone have any suggestions on adding this or how to go about adding it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TexturePacker comes with an exporter for CreateJS/EaselJS. It supports trimming.

CreateJS receives the sprite with the trimmed size but the registration point is adjusted to compensate for this.

Is it not working for you? What is happening?

Comment: When I turn on the trimming it is drawing the sprite without the alpha included.